# VMware installation "virtual machine monitor" error while compiling and loading running kernel module

Tags: boot, kernel, uefi, compiling, vmware

[image: asking for compiling and loading kernel module]

[image: showing error after clicking on install]

I tried to solve this problem most of the people recommend to disable secure boot in bios but i am unable to diable as i go in to my bios it is showing only options for efi and there is no such thing called secure boot.
And also tried to install build essentials nothing happened.
please help.

ubuntu - 16.04

Comment: Was it working before now?

Comment: Yes, disabling >Secure Boot should work. Please consult you manual and other online resources regarding your specific model. That part has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Note: Some UEFIs do not have an explicit setting for secure boot and instead do it through "OS Selection"  whereas "Windows" =  Secure Boot on and "Other/Android/Linux", etc. = Secure Boot off.

Comment: @George Nope i just installed it and after completion i ran that application and this message showed up

Comment: @MichaelBay i tried all possible ways of disabling it .I tried mokutils to disable then it is showing up "efi variables are not supported in this system"

Comment: If so post the hardware specs.

Comment: You can check your Secure Boot (SB) status from a running Ubuntu by typing `hexdump /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/SecureBoot-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c`. If the first line of output is `0000000 0016 0000 0001`, then SB is active; if it's `0000000 0016 0000 0000`, then it's inactive. If you get a `No such file or directory` error, then your system doesn't support SB at all. Although SB is a common cause of the sort of problem you're reporting, it's not the only possible cause, so you should check your SB status before investing more time in what might be a wild goose chase.

Comment: @RodSmith no such file or directory exist.
anyways i shifted to virtualbox it is working fine